# msoFileDialogSaveAs set default file name in dialogue window

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following VBA code to let the user choose a path to save a xlsm excel file as a xlsx file. The functionality is triggered by clicking a button in the xlsm excel file.

When I try it out, the name of the file in the saveas-window is empty, how can I set a default name (e.g. report_xyz) so the user does not have to type it himself?

```
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    'displays the result in a message box
    Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "File got saved as")
End If

' Set to a xlsx file from xlsm
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button
Worksheets("Import_Sheet").Delete 'Delete Import Sheet
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPath, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum  ' save with new name and format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Preset the "save as type" field while using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) with MSAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770030/preset-the-save-as-type-field-while-using-application-filedialogmsofiledialog)

i think
`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).InitialFileName = "test"`
before
`intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show`
will do the job

Comment: So simple... I saw the initialFileName attribute in the docs, but could not get it to work. Thanks!