# how can I print multiple lines into one csv cell from php?

Tags: php, arrays

how can I print multiple lines into one csv cell from php?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Payal(102)
            [1] => 01:14:22
            [2] => 00:58:14
            [3] => 02:12:36
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => Payal
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => VMail(902)
            [1] => 00:02:41
            [2] => 00:00:00
            [3] => 00:02:41
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 6
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 7
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => NadiaAbdoolla(113)
            [1] => 01:44:47
            [2] => 03:56:28
            [3] => 05:41:15
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 11
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => Nadia
            [13] => 2019-12-31 08:32:25
            [14] => 2019-12-31 15:57:49
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 08:32:25
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 12:35:50
                            [Total] => 4:3:25
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 12:40:44
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 14:13:41
                            [Total] => 1:32:57
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 14:14:01
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 15:57:49
                            [Total] => 1:43:48
                        )
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Huma(202)
            [1] => 00:43:10
            [2] => 02:25:32
            [3] => 03:08:42
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 2
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 0
            [12] => Huma
            [13] => 2019-12-31 13:11:55
            [14] => 2019-12-31 20:55:50
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 13:11:55
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 20:55:50
                            [Total] => 7:43:55
                        )
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Grace(203)
            [1] => 01:01:57
            [2] => 00:11:04
            [3] => 01:13:01
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 20
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 3
            [9] => 3
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 2
            [12] => Payal Panda
            [13] => 2019-12-31 13:20:56
            [14] => 2019-12-31 20:56:45
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 13:20:56
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 20:56:45
                            [Total] => 7:35:49
                        )
                )
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jarryd(207)
            [1] => 02:40:53
            [2] => 02:07:09
            [3] => 04:48:02
            [4] => 21
            [5] => 57
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 22
            [10] => 8
            [11] => 22
            [12] => Jarryd
            [13] => 2019-12-31 08:29:27
            [14] => 2019-12-31 15:51:02
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 08:29:27
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 15:51:02
                            [Total] => 7:21:35
                        )
                )
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Akhil(211)
            [1] => 02:06:45
            [2] => 00:02:07
            [3] => 02:08:52
            [4] => 17
            [5] => 27
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => Akhil
            [13] => 2019-12-31 11:09:37
            [14] => 2019-12-31 20:40:46
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 11:09:37
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 20:40:46
                            [Total] => 9:31:9
                        )
                )
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vishal(210)
            [1] => 02:28:07
            [2] => 02:32:59
            [3] => 05:01:06
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 77
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 4
            [9] => 29
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 25
            [12] => Vishal
            [13] => 2019-12-31 11:13:26
            [14] => 2019-12-31 19:46:23
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 11:13:26
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 19:46:23
                            [Total] => 8:32:57
                        )
                )
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Joanne(120)
            [1] => 01:18:43
            [2] => 00:00:00
            [3] => 01:18:43
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 46
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 3
            [8] => 3
            [9] => 18
            [10] => 5
            [11] => 16
            [12] => Joanne
            [13] => 2019-12-31 08:35:15
            [14] => 2019-12-31 15:54:34
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 08:35:15
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 12:08:44
                            [Total] => 3:33:29
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 12:09:28
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 12:23:50
                            [Total] => 0:14:22
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 12:30:20
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 14:02:53
                            [Total] => 1:32:33
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 14:05:07
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 14:11:04
                            [Total] => 0:5:57
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 14:11:39
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 14:28:32
                            [Total] => 0:16:53
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 14:30:57
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 14:45:47
                            [Total] => 0:14:50
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 14:46:34
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 15:24:04
                            [Total] => 0:37:30
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [In] => 2019-12-31 15:25:43
                            [Out] => 2019-12-31 15:54:34
                            [Total] => 0:28:51
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you [Adding a newline character within a cell (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018597/adding-a-newline-character-within-a-cell-csv/24020428)

```
csvString += "\""+"Date Generated: \n" ; 
csvString += "Doctor: " + "\n"+"\"" + "\n";
```