# Export multiple line in CSV (Not multi-property value into CSV)

Tags: powershell, csv

First of all I would like to clarify that my question is **NOT**: *How to export multi-valued properties (array) into csv file.*

My use case is the following: I am creating a code to audit Hyper-V infrastructure and I would like to have in one CSV cell multiple lines. For example: NIC1, NIC2 ... Disk 1, Disk 2. 
I do not want to use `join` operator and have it on a single line.

[image]

I am almost certain that there was an article about that and that i did managed to achieve the goal, but unfortunately I am not able to find neither the article, neither the scrip in which I have used it.

Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018597/adding-a-newline-character-within-a-cell-csv/24020428 Maybe this might be of help?

Answer (score 1):

The hint was submitted by **LeroyJD** in the comments. 
@LeroyJD, Thank you very much, helped a lot! :)

To summarize for future reference: Yes, it is possible by using the new line `backtick n` to present in multiple lines. Sample code:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Value1 = 'Hello'
    Value2 = "Hello `nWorld"
} | Export-Csv C:\TEMP\multiline.csv -NoTypeInformation

Invoke-Item C:\TEMP\multiline.csv
```

Which results into:

[image]

Thanks again to **LeroyJD** for the hint!