# Write new line character (\n) in csv cell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, linefeed

I am trying to create a csv file using npm package [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer). I read data from oracle database and some of the table columns contain line feed i-e CHR(10) and carriage return i-e CHAR(13). This disturbs csv format. I want to store these characters in same csv cell in the same csv line. Is there any way I can handle this without replacing these characters before writing csv and than replace back. If there is any JavaScript csv package that handles this it would be much appreciated if some body can include an example of it.
Thanks!

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/can-you-encode-cr-lf-in-into-csv-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you encode CR/LF in into CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/can-you-encode-cr-lf-in-into-csv-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a newline character within a cell (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018597/adding-a-newline-character-within-a-cell-csv)

Comment: @Ernesto Please don't make edits to questions to add indicates of duplicates. There is already a system to handle such cases: voting or flagging to close (as you also did).