# Adding line breaks within a cell

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, json2csv

I create a CSV from javascript array of objects using the [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) module. This is what I do

```
const list = [{name: "xyz", city: "abc"},{name: "foo", city: "def"}];

const json2csvParser = new Parser({fields: headers});
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(list);
```

Now, for the CSV created by converting array of objects, I need to prepend a row (add a new row at the top) and fill only the first cell. It will look similar to the following

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
const newLine = `"First Line
   Second Line"`;

const updatedCSV = newLine + csv;
```

Now, if I open this CSV using `google spreadsheet`, it shows the prepended value in cell, with line breaks. But if I open the same in `Microsoft Excel`, it shows as follows:

[image]

There are multiple rows created and `"` are also visible. How can I make it seamless, so that it opens the same everywhere, which always shows one row with multiple line breaks. I need to be able to add the line breaks within a cell.

I referred to

- [Adding a newline character within a cell (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018597/adding-a-newline-character-within-a-cell-csv)
- [Can you encode CR/LF in into CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/can-you-encode-cr-lf-in-into-csv-files)

but it did not help.

When I try to open the file using a text editor, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What does the actual csv file look like (open in a text editor like Notepad++). For Excel to honor the linebreak, you need to have double quotes `"` around the string. To display it, be sure to enable wordwrap for the cell(s).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have updated the screenshot, of how it looks like when opened with a text editor. As you can see, there are `"` around `How to use ... Column B`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It will be great, if you could provide a small example on how would you do it. I have been struggling with it for sometime now.

Comment: Your problem is at the very beginning.  The quote marks have to be around the **entire** entry and start either at the very beginning of the line, or **immediately** after a comma if not in the first cell.  Your opening quote mark, in the first line, is in the third position.  I suggest you delete the `| `  (pipe<space>) to obtain your desired result.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks that solved the issue. I think, this will make a very good answer. The response stream was adding 2 spaces and this went unnoticed.