# Python 3 reading CSV file with line breaks in rows

Tags: python, csv

I have a large CSV file with one column and line breaks in some of its rows. I want to read the content of each cell and write it to a text file but the CSV reader is splitting the cells with line breaks into multiple ones (multiple rows) and writing each one to a separate text file.

Using Python 3.6.2 on a MAC Sierra

Here is an example:

```
"content of row 1"
"content of row 2 
 continues here"
"content of row 3"
```

And here is how I am reading it:

```
with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvfile:

    lines= csv.reader(csvfile)

    i=0
    for row in lines:
        i+=1
        content= row

        outFile= open("output"+str(i)+".txt", 'w')

        outFile.write(content)

        outFile.close()
```

This is creating 4 files instead of 3 for each row. Any suggestions on how to ignore the line break in the second row?

Comment: That source CSV doesn't seem properly formatted as a CSV. Try using an editor like Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets. They'll output the CSV correctly, with cells containing special characters wrapped in quotation marks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/

Comment: is the row delimiter literally row#?  how can you tell when something is not a 'new' row

Comment: strip the row and check if it is equal to empty string before creating files.
Like this: ```content=row.strip()```

Comment: @andrewgu thanks but when I look at the file using vim the cells all are in quotation marks ""

Comment: @arsho thanks but this did not fix it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks. I tried adding newline= '' " but it did not work either

Comment: it's not possible for the csv module to differentiate between a new row and a multi-line row because you're missing the quotes in your input file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the rows actually have quotes. I just edited the example in my question to show that.

Comment: I just tested with a simple csv with quotes and it works fine.

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce. Can you 1) tell us your version of python 2) your operating system and 3) paste a raw sample (without the "row" prefixes) of your file, thus creating a [mcve]

Comment: also try adding `,quotechar='"'` to csv reader constructor (I doubt it will work)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited the question as requested to include python version and OS.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried adding quotechar= ' " ' but as you expected, it did not change anything

Comment: it still works fine here. python 3.4 windows. Sorry, cannot reproduce. Maybe it's an issue with invisible characters. Can you edit the file using hex editor? Can you try with the input you posted (in a new file) to convince yourself that your original input file has a problem. Because it works fine, as I said

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are right. It is working for the simple example for me too. There must be some different problem with my big CSV file

Comment: macintosh has a strange way to terminate lines. check hex editor between your simple file and your big file. Create little extracts of your big files. Check if lines end with 0D or 0D 0A or 0A... all the help I can offer, sorry.

Comment: This is in act the kind of CSV files that Microsoft Excel produces.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a regular expression pattern to help you iterate over the *rows*.

Read the entire file contents - if possible.

```
s = '''"content of row 1"
"content of row 2 
 continues here"
"content of row 3"'''
```

Pattern - double-quote, followed by anything that isn't a double-quote, followed by a double-quote.:

```
row_pattern = '''"[^"]*"'''
row = re.compile(row_pattern, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Iterate the rows:

```
for r in row.finditer(s):
    print r.group()
    print '******'

>>> 
"content of row 1"
******
"content of row 2 
 continues here"
******
"content of row 3"
******
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file you describe is NOT a CSV (comma separated values) file.  A CSV file is a list of records *one per line* where each record is separated from the others by commas.  There are various "flavors" of CSV which support various features for quoting fields (in case fields have embedded commas in them, for example).

I think your best bet would be to create an adapter class/instance which would pre-process the raw file, find and merge the continuation lines into records and them pass those to your instance of *csv.reader*.  You could model your class after [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) from the Python standard libraries.

The point is that you create something which processes data but behaves enough like a file object that it can be used, transparently, as the input source for something like *csv.reader()*.

(Done properly you can even implement the [Python context manager protocol](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).  [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO) does support this protocol and could be used as a reference.  This would allow you to use instances of this hypothetical "line merging" adapter class in a Python *with* statement just as you're doing with your open *file()* object in your example code).

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
data = u'1,"a,b",2\n2,ab,2.1\n'
with StringIO(data) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, quotechar='"')
    for rec in reader:
        print(rec[0], rec[2], rec[1])
```

That's just a simple example of using the *io.StringIO* in a *with* statement  Note that *io.StringIO* requires Unicode data, *io.BytesIO* requires "bytes" or string data (at least in 2.7.x).  Your adapter class can do whatever you like.

Comment: Yes it is a valid CSV file, check the spec at seciont 2.6 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: It is very much valid CSV. CSV file can contain CR/LF characters inside the field (column) but it needs to be quoted in such case.
As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) you can see that: _Fields containing a line-break, double-quote or commas should be quoted. (If they are not, the file will likely be impossible to process correctly.)_