# Adding new line into CSV when extracting HTML elements

Tags: python, csv

After days of research and hundreds of errors I've almost reached the goal of my code but still missing a little detail. Here I'm scraping a website for some information and extracting it into Excel. The problem I'm trying to overcome here is creating a new line for every carrier. Right now, the output is a single list and I cannot figure out how to break every carrier info string apart.

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

c_list = ['282131','365370','551712'] 
headers = ['Name','Unsafe Driving','d1','Crash Indicator','Hours Of Service','d2','Vehicle Maintenance','d3','CS/Alcohol','d4', 'HazMat','Driver Fitness','d5']
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 
a=[]
c=[]
for i in c_list:
    driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='MCSearch'])[2]"))).send_keys(i)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='search'])[2]"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BASICs']/p[2]/a"))).click()
    carrier = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="basicInfo"]/div/h3')))
    c = carrier.text
    tbl = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='valueRow sumData']")))
    tab = tbl.text.replace("\n",','.strip())
    tab = tab.split(",")
    a.append(c)
    for x in tab:
        a.append(x)  

with open('table.csv','w', encoding='utf8') as myFile:
     writer = csv.writer(myFile)
     writer.writerow(headers)
     writer.writerow(a)
```

Right now, the output looks like this [image: output]

but what I need is this:
[image: desiredOutput]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including sample data to be processed — your question really has nothing to with how the data was obtained.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered well at [Can you encode CR/LF in into CSV files?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/can-you-encode-cr-lf-in-into-csv-files)

Consider also reverse engineering multiple lines in Excel. To embed a newline in an Excel cell, press `Alt+Enter`. Then save the file as a .csv. You'll see that the double-quotes start on one line and each new line in the file is considered an embedded newline in the cell.

to save it as `.csv` file you need to double quote value so if there is , it will not break your `csv` column and escape `"` with `""`

```
for article in articles:
    ...
    # description = re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", " ", description)
    description = description.replace('"', '""')
    rows = '"%s","%s","%s","%s"\n' % (title, date, description, info)
    f.write(rows)
```

Comment: The `csv` module is capable of both handling embedded newlines and escaping quote characters if you use the right options, so doing it yourself like this it probably not necessary.