# PSCustomObject members to CSV within single cell

Tags: excel, powershell, pscustomobject, export-csv

EDIT:

For what it's worth, I was able to achieve something better, I think.  Hope it helps people:

[image]

Using:

```
$licenseSearchTerm = 'dyn'
$arrayResults = @()

foreach ($userWithLicense in $usersWithLicense[333..384]) {
    $userLicenses = $userWithLicense | Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail

    if ( $userLicenses | Where-Object { $_.SkuPartNumber -match $licenseSearchTerm } ) {
        $results = [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $userWithLicense.UserPrincipalName
            License   = $userLicenses.SkuPartNumber | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        $arrayResults += $results

        $userLicenses[1..$userLicenses.Count] | ForEach-Object {
            $results = [PSCustomObject]@{
                License= $_.SkuPartNumber
            }
            $arrayResults += $results
        }
    }
}
```

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
The following code...

```
$licenseSearchTerm = 'license'
$arrayResults = @()

foreach ($userWithLicense in $usersWithLicense[383..384]) {

    $userLicenses = $userWithLicense | Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail

    if ( $userLicenses | Where-Object { $_.SkuPartNumber -match $licenseSearchTerm } ) {

        $results = [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $userWithLicense.UserPrincipalName
            License   = $userLicenses.SkuPartNumber 
        }

        $arrayResults += $results
    }
}

# $arrayResults  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$arrayResults | Export-Csv -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\licenses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

outputs in a CSV file:

[image]

How do I output it like this:

[image]

The `$userLicenses.SkuPartNumber` object contains multiple members which show up in the console output as one line per item.

I tried `$userLicenses.SkuPartNumber -join ', '` for each PSCUstomObject which kinda works but it displays each item like this:

[image]

Next, I tried `$userLicenses.SkuPartNumber -join [Environment]::NewLine`
but this produces:

[image]

Any idea how to format it to look like in the second picture?

Comment: This is a Excel limitation rather than a PowerShell issue. Try this: export your expected excel workbook to a `.csv` file and reload it into excel...

Comment: Open the CSV file with a text editor like Notepad and see what the text really looks like.

Comment: @jdweng, (`Get-Content -Raw .\test.csv | Format-Hex`) lines are joined with a `[char]10`, but reloading this will still break the round-trip anyways.

Comment: @iRon, which variant are you referring to? -join ', ' or -join [Environment]::NewLine?

Comment: Okay, well, it's likely not -join ', '; with -join [Environment]::NewLine I tried opening it in Excel, saving it as CSV overwriting the file and reopening it. Didn't change the way it's displayed. Looks like screenshot 3. Same goes for the .xlsx format.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo, I am not referring to any of the PowerShell variant. [[Environment]::NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/566052/1701026) is the  correct way from a `Csv` point of view but an issue for Excel.

Comment: @iRon : The third example doesn't make a lot of sense.  Something else is happening like quotes or tabs.

Comment: As an aside: [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, [Excel has some quirks with respect to dealing with multiline fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668678/importing-csv-with-line-breaks-in-excel-2007) that sometimes prevent Excel from correctly round-trip via a `csv` file. Anyhow, a single `[char]10` line-delimiter appears to work (for me) if you simply open (*right-clicking the `csv` file in Windows Explorer and selecting `Open with` -> `Excel`*) the `.\Test.csv` resulted from the example below:
<sub>(I guess that some localization settings might also of importance)</sub>

```
$usersWithLicense =
    [PSCustomObject]@{ User = 'User1'; License = 'License1', 'License2', 'License3' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ User = 'User2'; License = 'License4', 'License5', 'License6' }

$usersWithLicense | Foreach-Object {
   $_.License = $_.License -Join [Char]10
   $_
} | Export-Csv .\Test.csv
```

You might also open the file from your script:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Null = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$pwd\Test.csv")
$Excel.Visible = $True
```

Comment: If I use this I get a similar output as in my third screenshot:

User License
User1 License1
License2 
License3" 
User2 License4
License5 
License6" 

I hope I'm not misunderstanding you. I've always been using the Excel -> Data -> Text to Columns function.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo - try just right-clicking the csv file in Windows Explorer and selecting "Open with -> Excel"

Comment: or: `$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application; $Null = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$pwd\Test.csv"); $Excel.Visible = $True`