# Cannot properly parse XML file into CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Trying to parse an XML file results in some rows formatted into CSV file properly, with others in not the expected format.

The PowerShell script that I am using is as follows:

```
[XML]$inputFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_InstanceLog - 1.xml'
$inputFile.Document.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_InstanceLog - 1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:"|" -Encoding:UTF8
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_InstanceLog - 1.csv'
```

Opening the XML file in Excel does give the expected results; but not so using the above PowerShell script.

What I expect to have, is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShZE7.png)

As would be evident from the image, the comments data is wrapped in the cell for the given row.

However, using the PowerShell script, results in a CSV file as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4iq.png)

The comments data for the particular row, spills onto the succeeding rows.

The XML data is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Row InsCompare="" RequestId="" FormId="762" DTC="24-Jan-2023 04:05:07 PM" ReportingDate="30-Sep-2022" Status="8" UserId="abc123" InstanceDocPath="" EncryptDocPath="" ErrorDocPath="ABC220930R31802M_24-01-23_04-05-08_Instance.html" RenderedExcelDocPath="" IsExtract="true" IsInstance="true" IsCims="true">
    <Params />
    <Comment></Comment>
  </Row>
  <Row InsCompare="" RequestId="" FormId="762" DTC="24-Jan-2023 04:15:06 PM" ReportingDate="30-Sep-2022" Status="3" UserId="abc123" InstanceDocPath="" EncryptDocPath="" ErrorDocPath="" RenderedExcelDocPath="" IsExtract="true" IsInstance="true" IsCims="true">
    <Params />
    <Comment>Some of the queries does not executed successfully: StressedMSME: This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet.   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object&amp; executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&amp; executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object&amp; executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at CommonClass.ClsSqlQuerys.FunPubStaReturnDataSet(Int32 ProviderId, String ParamStrQuery)
   at WebZeal.Controllers.CreateInstanceController.RightPubInsertInstanceLog(Int32 DDLFormId, DateTime ParamDTRptDate, Boolean PropPubBoolIsExtract, Boolean PropPubBoolIsInstance, ClsParameters[] Param)</Comment>
  </Row>
</Document>
```

Comment: I suspect that if you create a [mcve] from your question (b.t.w. what happens when you directly save it to a csv?), you will probably find out that this is actually a duplicate of [PSCustomObject members to CSV within single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77043046/1701026). In other words what do you expect the resulting `csv` look like? (please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77184678/edit) an example of that `csv` to the question, and try to [avoid images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))

Comment: Well the powershell script works as expected. It parses the columns while preserving the multi line text and separates them with the delimiter. 
When the delimiter is comma, Excel opens the file as expected .
When the delimiter is different (despite the .csv file extension), Excel cannot display it correctly.  
So there is nothing wrong with the file, but Excel cannot display it in this way. If you are planning to use this file as an input for another script, that is ok  But if you want to use this file to open with excel you should change the delimiter with comma.

Comment: @CemPolat This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The return in the comment field is giving issues.  I made the delimiter in the output file a pipe character.  See if following gives better results.  I'm using the Net Library Xml Linq to parse the file.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$rows = $doc.Descendants("Row")

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($row in $rows)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
   foreach($att in $row.Attributes())
   {
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $att.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $att.Value
   }
   foreach($element in $row.Elements())
   {
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $element.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $element.Value 
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table | Export-CSV -path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:"|"
```